# FontAwesome 5+ icons Won't Appear Properly in Programmatically Created Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, font-awesome, android-fonts

I'm trying to use the latest version of the FontAwesome typeface for a `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` that I created programmatically, but instead a box is shown containing a cross. I tried both `FontManager.getTypeface(activity!!.baseContext, FontManager.FONTAWESOME)` and `FontManager.getTypeface(activity!!.applicationContext, FontManager.FONTAWESOME)` but neither of these worked. I'm even using the latest `.otf` file provided by FontAwesone. I really don't understand what I've done wrong, because I followed all the instructions on the FontAwesome website. Is there a problem because the layout is created dynamically or something else?

**FontManager object**

```
object FontManager {
    private const val ROOT = "fonts/"
    internal const val FONTAWESOME = ROOT + "fontawesome5-free-regular.otf"

    internal fun getTypeface(context: Context, font: String): Typeface {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, font)
    }
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val mainRelativeLayout = RelativeLayout(activity)

        // Layout Parameters for relative layout items
        val rlpCVPrimary = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val rlpTVPrimaryIcon = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                .WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val rlpTVPrimaryText = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                .WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val rlpTVTitle = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val rlpCVSecondary = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val rlpTVSecondaryIcon = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val rlpTVSecondaryText = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

        // Accessing FontAwesome font
        val iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(activity!!.applicationContext, FontManager.FONTAWESOME)

        //
        val r = context!!.resources
        val fourDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4f, r.displayMetrics).toInt()
        val tenDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10f, r.displayMetrics).toInt()
        val thirtyDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30f, r.displayMetrics).toInt()

        // Creating RelativeLayouts for root layout
        val cvRLPrimary = RelativeLayout(context)
        val cvRLSecondary = RelativeLayout(context)

        // Creating CardViews
        val cvPrimary = context?.let { CardView(it) }
        when {
            cvPrimary != null -> {
                cvPrimary.radius = fourDp.toFloat()
                cvPrimary.setContentPadding(tenDp,tenDp,tenDp,tenDp)
                cvPrimary.useCompatPadding = true
                cvPrimary.cardElevation = fourDp.toFloat()
                cvPrimary.layoutParams = rlpCVPrimary
            }
        }
        rlpCVPrimary.setMargins(0, 0, 0, thirtyDp)

        val cvSecondary = context?.let { CardView(it) }
        when {
            cvSecondary != null -> {
                cvSecondary.radius = fourDp.toFloat()
                cvSecondary.setContentPadding(tenDp,tenDp,tenDp,tenDp)
                cvSecondary.useCompatPadding = true
                cvSecondary.cardElevation = fourDp.toFloat()
                cvSecondary.layoutParams = rlpCVSecondary
            }
        }
        rlpCVSecondary.setMargins(0, 0, 0, thirtyDp)

        /*
         * Creating Primary CardView items
         */
        // 'tvPrimaryIcon' TextView
        val tvPrimaryIcon = TextView(context)
        tvPrimaryIcon.text = getString(R.string.fa_icon_sign_in)
        tvPrimaryIcon.typeface = iconFont
        tvPrimaryIcon.layoutParams = rlpCVPrimary
        tvPrimaryIcon.setMargins(0, 0, tenDp, 0)
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tvPrimaryIcon, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium)

        // 'tvPrimaryText' TextView
        val tvPrimaryText = TextView(context)
        tvPrimaryText.text = getString(R.string
                .primary_title)
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tvPrimaryText, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium)


        // 'tvTitle' TextView
        val tvTitle = TextView(context)
        tvTitle.text = getString(R.string.hello_world)
        tvTitle.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tvTitle, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium)
        rlpTVTitle.setMargins(0, tenDp, 0, tenDp)

        /*
         * Creating Secondary CardView items
         */
        // 'tvSecondaryIcon' TextView
        val tvIconExit = TextView(context)
        tvIconExit.text = getString(R.string.fa_icon_sign_out)
        tvIconExit.typeface = iconFont
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tvIconExit, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium)
        rlpTVIconExit.setMargins(0, 0, tenDp, 0)

        // 'tvSecondaryText' TextView
        val tvSecondaryText = TextView(context)
        tvSecondaryText.text = getString(R.string.secondary_title)
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tvSecondaryText, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium)


        // Set IDs for text views
        mainRelativeLayout.id = View.generateViewId()
        cvPrimary!!.id = View.generateViewId()
        tvPrimaryIcon.id = View.generateViewId()
        tvPrimaryText.id = View.generateViewId()
        tvTitle.id = View.generateViewId()
        cvSecondary!!.id = View.generateViewId()
        tvSecondaryIcon.id = View.generateViewId()
        tvSecondaryText.id = View.generateViewId()

        // Set Layout Parameters for text views
        tvPrimaryIcon.layoutParams = rlpTVPrimaryIcon
        tvPrimaryText.layoutParams = rlpTVPrimaryText
        tvTitle.layoutParams = rlpTVTitle
        tvSecondaryIcon.layoutParams = rlpTVSecondaryIcon
        tvSecondaryText.layoutParams = rlpTVSecondaryText

        // Set RelativeLayout rules for views
        rlpTVPrimaryText.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, tvPrimaryIcon.id)
        rlpTVTitle.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, cvPrimary.id)
        rlpCVSecondary.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tvTitle.id)
        rlpTVSecondaryText.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, tvSecondaryIcon.id)

        // Adding items to root layout
        mainRelativeLayout.addView(cvPrimary)
        cvPrimary.addView(cvRLPrimary)
        cvRLPrimary.addView(tvPrimaryIcon)
        cvRLPrimary.addView(tvPrimaryText)
        mainRelativeLayout.addView(tvTitle)
        mainRelativeLayout.addView(cvSecondary)
        cvSecondary.addView(cvRLSecondary)
        cvRLSecondary.addView(tvSecondaryIcon)  
        cvRLSecondary.addView(tvSecondaryText)

        return mainRelativeLayout
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have `assets/fonts/fontawesome5-free-regular.otf` in your project? Do you get the same box-with-cross if you skip the `iconFont` and just display things like `R.string.fa_icon_sign_out` with the default font?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes to both questions

Comment: With `iconFont` set to the FontAwesome font, try setting a `TextView` to something human-readable, such as "MacaronLover". If you see "MacaronLover" when you run the app, that suggests that `Typeface.createFromAsset()` either is not finding the font asset or doesn't like the font, and so it is falling back to the default. In that case, see if LogCat has any messages that seem relevant, and add an instrumented test to confirm that you do have `assets/fonts/fontawesome5-free-regular.otf` (if you don't have such a test already).

Comment: Note that my "MacaronLover" test assumes that FontAwesome uses the full ASCII set for glyphs -- if it uses real letters there, then that test won't work.

Comment: "MacaronLover" appeared when I set the TextView to that, but I noticed that after opening the font file, the full alphabet and numerals appear rather than boxes or question marks. Strange. See attached screenshot. I also get an error in the debugger 'icon = Unresolved reference: icon'

Comment: OK, it's possible that FontAwesome leaves the basic ASCII stuff alone. Basically, I'm trying to determine if the FontAwesome font is even being used by your app, or if it is falling back to the default. That may be difficult to tell with plain letters and numbers. FWIW, [this issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/13903) suggests that the FontAwesome folks aren't really supporting using FontAwesome in an Android app.

Comment: Page not found, lol

Comment: Sorry, try the link now.

Comment: What an absolute shame and disgrace for FontAwesome. Now I have to go through the process of creating 2 different coloured versions (black & white) of every XML drawable icon I want. FontAwesome handled this perfectly.

Comment: @MacaronLover you can always **Tint** the drawable, no need to create two versions

Comment: @OmarMainegra is there a recommended color (like black) that I should set to the drawable first before applying any tinting?

Comment: I would say, make the default color the one you use the most, and tint the others, or maybe tint every `ImageView` with the corresponding color (it's more explicit and less error prone)